# iphone xmpp related !

Tags: iphone, xmpp

I am able to chat successfully using xmpp, but now I have following queries:

1. Is it possible to register to openfire server from iphone (using xmpp iphone sdk) ? If yes, then how ? (at least give me a hint)
2. Is it possible to chat with another user without add to him in a contact list, suppose I want to chat with all those users who are online...? If yes then how ?? (any hint ??)
3. Is it possible to manage friends, ie. sending friend request, responding to friend request(accept/reject) and reading pending notification requests ??

Programming Language: Objective C
Technology : iPhone SDK
Framework/API : xmpp opensource API

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read these documents:

- [XMPP: Core](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120) (you didn't ask questions related to this, but you'll need it to understand the others)
- [XMPP: IM and Presence](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121) (roster management, seending IM)
- [In-band registration](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html) (registering new user accounts)

Then you'll want to check if XMPPFramework supports the protocols you want already, or whether you need to add them yourself.